# How can I define or solve this error for hadoop streaming?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, emr, amazon-emr

I got some errors for hadoop mr job, how can I define this problem for hadoop streaming?

```
Error: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of input stream
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:85)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:47)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of input stream
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:85)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:47)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)
```

(unfortunately I don't have permission to post any source code)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience,but I don't have any permission to open our source code. Actually I resolved this problem with option. -m mapred.max.map.failures.percent=1

Comment: And I wanna know how to deal with the corrupted file (.gzip)for mapping data in the mapper. Is there any options for skipping the corrupted files?

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping you resolved this somehow.
But there are probably empty files that constitute a part of the table you are querying or the directory / batch reading from.

Running with a check for safeguarding against the occurrence of files with size 0 would be great.

Answer (score 0):

These error logs are not helping much. Since you dont have the permission to share the code, you can try the following steps.

1. Check the dependent libraries used in your code is present in all the nodes of your hadoop cluster. This is required because the task may execute in any of the worker nodes.
2. Get a sample input file and execute the code locally before running it as a mapreduce program. You can execute it locally in the following way.

   *cat sampleinput | python mappercode.py*

Comment: Thank you, Amal, but I want to know how to check the validity of many files.(*.zip)

Comment: Are these zip files present in hdfs.

Comment: yes, but a few files are corrupted. For example, the size of gzip file is 13MB. However there is no contents in the gzip file. I want to know how to check the validation of gzip files before running mr job.